# How to write down the gpio-expander to the kernel device tree?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree

I use a GPIO expander (TCA6424) with i.mx8qm. The expander is connected with the processor through I²C. I wrote it down to the **.dts* file:

```dts
&i2c4 {
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c4>;
        status = "okay";
    tca6424@22 {
        compatible = "ti, tca6424";
        reg = <0x22>;
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
    };
};
```

But the driver outputed the errors:

```
[    0.816053] pca953x 8-0020: 8-0020 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.823139] pca953x 8-0020: failed reading register
[    0.827936] pca953x: probe of 8-0020 failed with error -5
```

Do I understand correctly 0x22 is address of device here? But where I should write down the number of I²C bus? What else could I forget to point out?

Comment: Are you sure you are using an ARM8 from 1996? Not a Cortex-A8, or perhaps a ARMv8? The actual SoC / processor model would be even more important to know.

Comment: Sorry),thanks for the note, sure, i use i.mx8qm

Comment: No, the probed is the device on bus 8 (**8**-0020) with address 0x20 (8-**0020**). In your DTS is a typo — extra space in the compatible string.

Comment: Thanks for the typo. Why is the probed on bus and address 8-0020 and not probed on 8-0022? I wrote down reg = <0x22> in the dts.

Comment: Probe is failed. With information you given it is not clear what’s going on. Definitely the dmesg and DTs are **not** from the same device. P.S. to notify user in the comments use `@username` in it.